# How to reference views (e.g. Spinner value) from ViewModel

Tags: android, android-view, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to reference a *Spinner* view and its value from `HomeViewModel` that is populated with a list of strings in the `HomeFragment` and declared in the *XML* layout file of the fragment.

This spinner contains a list of languages.

Depending on which language is selected, I assign a different variable through `spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()` in the `HomeViewModel`. Problem is, `spinner` is not defined or referenced there, and I wouldn't do the processing on my `HomeFragment` because I'll run some heavy code on it so as not to block it. How do I call the spinner? Is it wrong to use the `HomeViewModel` as a kind of coroutine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never do this because it causes a memory leak. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#implement):

> Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.

What if you create a view model's method passing the selected language as parameter and call the method from within the view (*Fragment*)?